# How to get SNMP on HP StoreOnce working?

Tags: backup, nagios, snmp, hpe

I'm trying to add HPE StoreOnce 3640 Gen4 to the Nagios using SNMP v3 (other SNMP versions aren't supported in this device), and I'm stuck. It has the SW version 4.2.1-1942.21.

This is not the first time configuring SNMP v3; I'v done it already on Mikroitk devices, Eltex devices, Cisco devices and even (for testing) configured snmpd on the Linux machine. However, this one doesn't work.

As described in [the HPE manual](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00117872en_us&page=viewing_configuring_snmp.html), I'm creating the SNMP user `nagios`, selected the mode "authentication and privacy" (which requires to specify two passwords), set the authentication mode "SHA" and password, and privacy mode "AES" and another password. Enabled the SNMP agent, and it says "enabled" in the web interface.

Then, from the neighbor machine I run:

```
snmpwalk  -v3 -u nagios -l authPriv -a SHA -A <authPW> -x AES -X <privPW> 192.168.221.150 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.36.1.1.5.1.12
```

(this OID is described as "Version number for this device's hardware" in the [MIB](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/softwaredetails?language=en_US&softwareId=co-86591-2&tab=releaseNotes)) and nothing happens. It says: `snmpwalk: Timeout`. `tcpdump` shows that StoreOnce just doesn't answer. Obviously, I can't check whether it is listening, because it's UDP. Nmap with UDP scan says the port 161 is filtered (however, this is not the definitive test, due to UDP nature).

I am sure both passwords are correct (and I tried to swap them, just to be sure). I am sure there is no network firewall between the device and the server, they are in the same IP subnet. Also I've tried to create a ordinary "web interface" user in StoreOnce with the same name, just for the case. Running similar command against Linux SNMP agent on another neighbor machine works fine (of course, there is no such OID on Linux machine, I walked just through 1.3.6.1), so I am sure I use `snmpwalk` correctly.

Probably I am missing something in the StoreOnce configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try enableing snmp on the subnet config

On the main menu, select Settings.
In the Hardware section, click the Networking panel.
On the Networking screen, select Edit configuration on the Actions menu.
On the Edit Configuration screen, click the edit icon ( ) for the port set.
On the Port Set screen, do one of the following:

Click its edit icon () on the Subnets panel. On the Subnet screen, click Edit subnet on the Actions menu. Use the Edit Subnet dialog to change settings.

Settings for adding and editing a subnet

Services (optional). All subnets can be configured to provide access to a mixture of data interface types. Select the protocols that are required to be accessible through this interface.

iSCSI protocol (RMC) (mutually exclusive with VTL)

iSCSI protocol (VTL) (mutually exclusive with RMC)

NAS (CIFS and NFS)

Catalyst and Replication

SNMP

When you are ready, click OK.

Comment: Yea, this helped! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Well, although it now answers SNMP, its answers are somewhat strange. Maybe you can explain why it says `SEMI-MIB::hpHttpMgDeviceHealth.1 = INTEGER: 0` (OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.36.1.1.5.1.1.3.1`, 1 is the device index), which is in the MIB described as general status and meaningful values are 1 to 6 where 3 means "ok"? What "0" means is not described. Also, I don't see any networking information in `SEMI-MIB::hpHttpMgEntityNetInfoEntry` (`1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.36.1.1.3.1.1`), it says "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID".